# affordable cloud space for a duplicity backup?

Tags: ftp, webdav, cloud

I'm searching for around 1TB of cloud space for backup using the Unix/Linux [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/index.html) backup tool? Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has recently launched Glacier  that could be used for duplicity backup if you don't mind waiting 3-5 hours for your data when you need it.

They did not release the API for it so you'll have to use what you can find online in terms of working with it. But this amount will cost you 10$ a month which is really affordable.

Comment: FYI—they released an API at the same time. See http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/glacier/

Comment: I was referring to a command line API, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I don't think Amazon has any official CLI interfaces. But third-parties make them, e.g., https://github.com/carlossg/glacier-cli

Comment: That's what I meant by "you'll have to use what you can find online".

Comment: I thought you had to download your data over several days to avoid gigantic charges